# 2 .jar files not interacting with each other

Tags: java

I have recently been adding an updater to my Java programm and all the code is working.  The problem I am having however is that the initial program doesn't go on to run the second .jar file or even run the file in NetBeans and just shuts down instead.

I believe this bit of code to be the thing that isn't working but I have done a tonne of System.out's and it just runs straight through the code without running the second programme:

```
private void update() {
    String[] run = {"java", "-jar", "updater/update.jar"};
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(run);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

My folders/files are in this path:

```
LibTiles.jar   (initial file that runs this code)
updater/update.jar
```

Can anyone see any errors or have I done something wrong in another place?

Answer (score 1):

I believe java.exe is not in your PATH environment.

In addition, try to start java.exe, or better, javaw.exe with your file (add the .exe), like this:

```
String[] run = {"java.exe", "-jar", "updater/update.jar"};
```

If you don't want the console window, use:

```
String[] run = {"javaw.exe", "-jar", "updater/update.jar"};
```

Comment: how would i go about changing it from a .jar to a .exe?

Comment: No, you don't change the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of your question is terribly confusing.  You mention LibTiles.jar and you post a snippet that runs the main method in updater/update.jar.  Does the code in update.jar require .class files in LibTiles.jar?

I can think of two possible problems, both caused by the lack of a manifest in your update.jar.  It has to say what the main method is, and it also contains the classpath.  I'd recommend that you read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html).

You should also write your method using Process, like this [example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html):

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public class DoProcessBuilder {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

       if (args.length <= 0) {
         System.err.println("Need command to run");
         System.exit(-1);
       }

       Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
       InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String line;

       System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", 
          Arrays.toString(args));

       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
       }

     }
  }
```